# PHP function to escape string for writing into executable PHP file

Tags: php, security

I need to handle untrusted input that will be written into a file that is executed by the server, `config.php`, like this:

```
$config['key'] = "Value";
```

I want to make it so that the user can submit a form which will write `config.php`. It obviously makes more sense to store this value in a database, but I cannot do that because this is a legacy system.

I found the functions `addslashes` and `serialize`, but I'm not sure if they are safe for this use case. I also could use `hex2bin/bin2hex` I suppose.

Another hack I thought of was using HEREDOCs:

```
$x = <<<PASSWORD

untrusted input here" echo "BOOM!";

PASSWORD;
```

What is the best way to proceed in this situation if you cannot change how configuration variables are stored?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php & 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Comment: `var_export` would be fine for this purpose.

Comment: It's a bad idea to store run-time writable config in a PHP file. Even if your PHP-syntax-output is completely correct, you still have to give the web user run-time write access to executable files, which means any file-upload vulnerability will escalate to an execute-arbitrary-code vulnerability. If you can't store to a database, at least store to a flat non-executable file (eg text or JSON) which can be read from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 the content. Anything base64'ed can't possibly be valid PHP code